# Configure a Sharepoint app to allow the Host web to read its list

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I want to build a  lookup site column in the host web that can use a list  in the app web.

Pretty much we are building an appl  that uses an internal list to handle some business logic that the app controls.

We want to be able to use a lookup column in the hostWeb that  will only accept values that are inside the list in the AppWeb.

Is It possible to do this?

Currently We are having to make a new list in the HostWeb  and having the app to write to both list  ( the list in the App Web  and the list in the HostWeb).   This means for any changes to the list, we have to make changes to both list in the AppWeb and in the HostWeb.

First tried to use Taxonomy Terms but since you cannot update Taxonomy Terms in a REST call (this is needed as the app is running the workflow and the taxonomy column is inside the hostWeb) inside of a sharepoint 2013 workflow,  we had to change the site column to a lookup column

Comment: What are you asking? Can you edit this to form a question? What have you tried?